# Validation of viewstate MAC failed in JMeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I'm getting this error after running the script in jmeter tool.

[image: JMeter screenshot]

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a
>   Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies
>   the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot
>   be used in a cluster.

Dev team has enabled `machineKey=true`

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you didn't correlate [VIEWSTATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) parameter, you need to extract it from each response and add as a parameter to the next request. Normally people use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) for this.

See [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) article for details.